# Edubuntu 14.04 Edubuntu menu editor not opening

Tags: 14.04

I installed Edubuntu 14.04 LTS on different machines for a testing purpose, but the Menu editor is not opening on any of them; you click and it is not opening at all. however the same icon is working on Ubuntu 12.04 test machine

Answer (score 1):

The `gmenu` package may not be installed. To install it, run:

```
sudo apt-get install gmenu
```

Answer (score 1):

I was observing the same issue on my installation (Edubuntu 14.04.1). Running `sudo apt-get install gmenu` as suggested by Matt gave an error, *"unable to locate package gmenu"*.

I've noticed that `python-gmenu` is installed in Edubuntu 12 but not in Edubuntu 14.

Running `sudo apt-get install python-gmenu` fixed menu editor. It can open now.

"Edubuntu Menu Editor - Profile Manager" menu is missing in my Edubuntu installation.

I've created another menu item and gave it this command copied from Linux Mint installation:

```
gksu --desktop /usr/share/applications/profilemanager.desktop profilemanager
```

NOTE: I also installed `gksu` since it wasn't present.